# File refuses to compile std::erase() even if using -std=g++23

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-errors, g++, clang++

I'm having a huge problem.
I have a struct

```cpp
struct Particle {
    int x = -1;
    int y = -1;
    int type = -1;
    int number = -1;

    bool operator==(Particle p) {
        if (this->x == p.x && this->y == p.y && this->type == p.type 
            && this->number == p.number) { return true; }
        else { return false; }
    }
};
```

and an array of vectors of them `std::vector<Particle> energies[5];` on which I call the method `std::erase(energies[neighbor.type], neighbor);`

The problem I have is that compiling using `g++ crystal.cpp -std=c++23 -o crystal $(root-config --cflags --glibs)` (the latter part is for the CERN ROOT library which I need in my program) gives me the compiler error

```
$: g++ crystal.cpp -std=c++23 -o crystal `root-config --cflags --glibs`
crystal.cpp: In lambda function:
crystal.cpp:94:22: error: ‘erase’ is not a member of ‘std’
std::erase(energies[neighbor.type], neighbor);
```

and I have no clue why that is.

Running `g++ --version` says I have 13.2.1 and that function should have been added in version 9 according to this table https://en.cppreference.com/w/Template:cpp/compiler_support/20. The error I get is the same if I substitute g++ with clang++.

Running the mock code

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

struct Particle {
    int x = -1;
    int y = -1;
    bool operator==(Particle p) {
        if (this->x == p.x && this->y == p.y)  { return true; }
        else { return false; }
    }
};

int main() {
    std::vector<Particle> v = {{1, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}};
    Particle to_erase = {1, 0};
    std::erase(v, to_erase);
    for (auto &entry : v) { 
        std::cout << entry.x << ' ' << entry.y << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

in an online compiler https://www.onlinegdb.com/ compiles and works as expected.
I have absolutely no idea why this case of "doesn't work on my machine" has struck me, but I couldn't find any issues akin to mine online.
Please help, I'm desperate.

EDIT: adding minimal non-working example

```cpp
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include "TApplication.h"
#include "TRandom3.h"
#include "TGraph.h"
#include "TSystem.h"
#include "TPad.h"
#include "TCanvas.h"
//#include <unistd.h>
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>

struct Particle {
    int x = -1;
    int y = -1;
    int type = -1;
    int number = -1;

    bool operator==(Particle const&) const = default;
};

int main() {
    TApplication app("app", 0, 0);

    TRandom3 rng;
    rng.SetSeed(12345);

    int mat_size = 50;
    int max_particles = 10;

    Particle empty_site = {-1, -1, -1, -1};

    std::vector<std::vector<Particle>> positions;
    for (auto &vector : positions) {
        std::fill(std::begin(vector), std::end(vector), empty_site);
    }

    std::vector<Particle> energies[5];
    // manual memory allocation
    for (auto &vector : energies) {
        vector.reserve(max_particles);
    }

    // Periodic Boundary Conditions
    auto Index = [&mat_size](int i) -> int {
        return ((i % mat_size) + mat_size) % mat_size;
    };

    auto MoveIn = [&positions, &energies, &Index, &empty_site] (int x, int y, int number) -> void {
        Particle neighbors[4] = {positions[Index(y+1)][x], positions[y][Index(x-1)], positions[Index(y-1)][x], positions[y][Index(x+1)]};
        int num_neighbors = 0;
        for (auto &neighbor : neighbors) {
            if (neighbor.type != empty_site.type) {
                // calculate number of neighbors for that site
                num_neighbors++;

                // update neighbor at energy with new energy
                std::erase(energies[neighbor.type], neighbor);
                neighbor.type++;
                energies[neighbor.type].push_back(neighbor);

                // update neighbor at position with new energy
                positions.at(neighbor.y).at(neighbor.x) = neighbor;
            }
        }
        // insert particle in site
        Particle deposited = {x, y, num_neighbors, number};

        // update positions and energies with the corrected particles
        positions.at(y).at(x) = deposited;
        energies[deposited.type].push_back(deposited);
    };

    app.Run(true);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: this comparator operator is functionally identical to the default one for simple data classes like this one; the only difference is that it takes another `Particle` by value, but should absolutely take it by const reference.

Comment: which one of the lines in the example code you post is line 94 that the compiler complains about? None! You need to show us the actual code that causes the problem, not some other code!

Comment: I added it because on the online compiler it told me an issue was that there was no operator==, so I assumed it was needed. Looking online some people also said that structs do not have a default operator==, so I added it. Indeed if I do remove it, the online compiler gives out the error that it lacks it.

Comment: Nice, but now the compiler complains about line 94, not the code that you show.You should also try to make sure the error happens without you including and linking to root, as well. Maybe manually check the output `root-config --cflags --glibs`: Maybe they do horrible things! (wouldn't be the first time, I stopped using root when I realized what a packaging and build nightmare it is, years ago)

Comment: `bool operator==(Particle const&) const = default;`

Comment: line 94 is literally just `std::erase(energies[neighbor.type], neighbor);`.
It's inside a lambda but I doubt that's the problem. It's as if the erase function just didn't exist. If I had to remove root then I might as well just move to a different language: it's the only reason I'm using C++. It's the only plotting library I know of that can make animations and that's not python (which is WAY too slow for what I have to do).

Comment: All those `this->`s give me a headache. Not to mention the redundancy in the code of those `operator==`s. `return x == p.x && y == p.y and type == p.type && number == p.number;` is all that's needed.

Comment: Side note: nothing in this code needs the extra stuff that `std::endl` does. Use `'\n'` to end a line unless you have a good reason not to.

Comment: Please show a [mcve] for non working code. The working [mcve] is useless in answering.

Comment: Interestingly, using that default operator== gives the error `error: defaulted ‘bool Particle::operator==(const Particle&) const’ only available with ‘-std=c++20’ or ‘-std=gnu++20’` so most likely for whatever reason, my compiler is ignoring the tag `-std=c++23`

Comment: Can't replicate https://godbolt.org/z/5vfhcxzxb

Comment: `-std=g++23` is invalid option. It must be either `-std=c++23` or `-std=gnu++23`. Your question looks like a typo.

Comment: That's not minimal and neither is it reproducible...

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/v9j1q5fh5 - compiles w/o errors after removing the unknown `T...` types.

Comment: yes, the "unknown T... types" are part of CERN ROOT's library which I need in other parts of the program, as I said in the question.